# Query Select with multiple tables and needing Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a Select command to combine 3 tables.

GROUPS, I want to see every record of this table where the table meets the WHERE for the table
CONTACTS, I want to see contacts that meet certain conditions, if there are no contacts I still want to see the GROUP records in the query
GROUPCONTACTS, this table sits between GROUPS and CONTACTS to allow for a many-to-many relationship.

I have tried the following but it shows me every GROUPCONTACTS record instead of just those where there is a related CONTACTS that matches the query. I do not know if SQL allows for what I want.

Azure server running MSSQL server.

```
SELECT G.GroupID, GC.ContactID, C.ContactID, C.Status, C.Type
    FROM Groups G

LEFT JOIN GroupContacts GC
    ON GC.GroupID = G.GroupID

JOIN Contacts C
    ON C.ContactID = GC.ContactID
    AND C.Type = 'Manager'
    AND C.Status = 'Active'
 
WHERE G.Status = 'Active' AND G.Type = 'Physician'
```

I was hoping to see 1951 results showing 1 record per GROUPS whether or not there was a matching CONTACT. Instead I got 1550 results, excluding all GROUPS that didn't have a matching CONTACT.

I hope I am explaining this well enough How can I have the table Contacts JOIN with GroupContacts and then in turn have the results LEFT JOIN with GROUPS?

Sample source tables
GROUP

| GroupID | Type | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Physician | Drs. Bennett & Stein | Active |
| 2 | Physician | Drs. Kogan & Larson | Inactive |
| 6 | Physician | Diagnostic Imaging | Active |

GROUPCONTACTS

| GroupContactID | GroupID | ContactID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13258 | 2227 | 124 |
| 13259 | 2305 | 138 |
| 13260 | 526 | 251 |
| 13261 | 2900 | 351 |
| 13262 | 1363 | 371 |
| 13263 | 2408 | 460 |
| 13264 | 417 | 511 |

CONTACTS

| ContactID | Type | First Name | Last Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 375 | Physician | Mervyn L. | Elgart | Inactive |
| 376 | Physician | Stephen S. | Elgin | Inactive |
| 377 | Physician | Oscar | Ellison III | Active |
| 378 | Physician | Michael | Emmer | Active |

RESULTS (Ideal)

| GroupID | ContactID | ContactID | Status | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3177 | 36187 | 36187 | Active | Manager |
| 3178 | 36188 | 36188 | Active | Manager |
| 3179 | 36189 | 36189 | Active | Manager |
| 3180 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

If a GROUPS doesn't have a matching GROUPCONTACT record just show the last 4 fields as NULL. The reason for the 2 ContactIDs is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Just simple data so we can understand what you need.

Comment: Please see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without seeing a schema and data it is difficult to help... a quick thing to try would by doing a LEFT JOIN to Contacts instead of just a JOIN and see if that gives you what you want. You can almost certainly do what you are trying to do, but without knowing the schema and seeing some data it is difficult to offer meaningful help.

Comment: @PaulC: I added empty line before, and after, each table to make it look nice....

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please post the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` setup statements. I created all those statements only to realize that the data in `GroupContacts` table doesn't match any of the sample data in `Groups` or `Contacts`. Fix the data. Include an example of data that is excluded but you think should be included. Then I'll update my answer.

```
CREATE TABLE Groups (
  GroupID int not null
  , Type nvarchar(50) not null
  , Name nvarchar(50) not null
  , Status nvarchar(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO Groups (GroupID, Type, Name, Status)
VALUES
   (1, 'Physician', 'Drs. Bennett & Stein', 'Active')
  , (2, 'Physician', 'Drs. Kogan & Larson','Inactive')
  , (6, 'Physician', 'Diagnostic Imaging', 'Active')
;

CREATE TABLE GroupContacts (
  GroupContactID int not null
  , GroupID int not null
  , ContactID int not null
);

INSERT INTO GroupContacts (GroupContactID, GroupID, ContactID)
VALUES 
  (13258,2227,124)
  , (13259,2305,138)
  , (13260,526,251)
  , (13261,2900,351)
  , (13262,1363,371)
  , (13263,2408,460)
  , (13264,417,511)
;

CREATE TABLE Contacts (
  ContactID int not null
  , Type nvarchar(50) not null
  , FirstName nvarchar(50) not null
  , LastName nvarchar(50) not null
  , Status nvarchar(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO Contacts (ContactID, Type, FirstName, LastName, Status)
VALUES 
  (375,'Physician','Mervyn L.','Elgart','Inactive')
  , (376,'Physician','Stephen S.','Elgin','Inactive')
  , (377,'Physician','Oscar','Ellison III','Active')
  , (378,'Physician','Michael','Emmer','Active')
;

SELECT G.GroupID, GC.ContactID, C.ContactID, C.Status, C.Type
FROM Groups G
  LEFT JOIN GroupContacts GC
    ON GC.GroupID = G.GroupID

  LEFT JOIN Contacts C
    ON C.ContactID = GC.ContactID
    AND C.Type = 'Manager'
    AND C.Status = 'Active'
 
WHERE G.Status = 'Active' AND G.Type = 'Physician'
```

| GroupID | ContactID | ContactID | Status | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NoGmatU5)

Comment: I realized that what I need to do is create a VIEW and then LEFT JOIN that VIEW to the QUERY of a Table. I hadn't worked with Views before but my limited experience in MS Access made me think this was the solution. However, I am still going to try to put together what Tim Jarosz requested because I am interested if I could do this without a VIEW.

Comment: You don't need a view. The `SELECT` you posted will work. It may be as simple as changing `JOIN Contacts` into `LEFT OUTER JOIN Contacts`. Since we can't see your sample data, I'm still making an educated guess.